# Ajax using GET to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have seen many posts close to this but not this specifically so I will still ask it.  I have a simple webpage that I am using to pass a value from to a server and then based on the value pass a response to the original webpage.  Right now for testing purposes I am just using an alert for the final value.

My client side code is as follows submitAjax.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#thisForm").submit(function () {
                    processData();
                });

                function processData() {
                    $.get('ajaxSubmit.php', function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" id="thisForm">
            <tr>    
                <td><input type=text name=box ></td>            
                <td><input type=submit value=Add></td>
            </tr> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server side ajaxSubmit.php:

```
<?php
$value=$_GET["box"];
if ($value==2){
    echo "This is the returned text.".$value;
}else{
    echo "not sent";
}
?>
```

As you can see from the code, I am trying to print the text "This is the returned text.2" as the output but when I enter "2" into the textbox my failure case of "not sent" is returned.

Any help would be great.  I am very very new to all things javascript so please point out anything else I am doing incorrectly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing anything when you're requesting `ajaxSubmit.php`.

```
$.get('ajaxSubmit.php?box=' + $("[name='box']").val(), function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

So you want to request, `ajaxSubmit.php?box=value`, where value is the value of the html element named `box`.

Comment: Thanks!  That got it working.  I am still a bit confused as to how this works but I will play with it and try to understand the workflow.